Case is not mapping to account in screen flow
I have created the screen flow which will be invoked when 'create new case' button on account details page is clicked. It then invokes a flow which will create a new case associated with the respective account.
I have added global variable recordid to hold accountid , which will pass accountid value to accountid  field in case which looks like this :

It is creating a new case as expected but case is not getting mapped with the account.

Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read How to Ask. Is the variable you are using as an input variable name recordId and set as 'Available for Input'?

I set it as available for input. But name is not recordId. Is is mandatory to name it as recordId ?

Yes, you have to set the input variable as recordId

Callum MacErlich thanks

Posting an answer here for anyone else that has a similar issue.
When using a Record ID from a Quick Action on a Record Page, the variable you are passing the record ID into must be configured as the following:

Type set to 'Text'
Named 'recordId' - This naming convention must be used, otherwise Salesforce will not set the value
Set as 'Available for input' - Likewise, without enabling the variable to be available for input the variable can't be populated from outside of the Flow itself

It is worth noting as well, that you can only pass the recordId into the Flow, and if you need to access the record itself you need to retrieve the record within the Flow based on the passed record Id.
Source: Flow Action Considerations
